# Does anyone know about char a[' ']?

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

What does `char a[' ']` actually mean? I didn't find it in web. I tried it by my self and it takes **dynamic array of char**. What is the purpose and use of `[' ']` in programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this definition

```
char a[' '];
```

character literal ' ' is promoted to int and its value is used as the size of the array. For example in ASCII the value of ' ' is equal to 32. So this is equivalent to

```
char a[32];
```

Take into account that in EBCDIC the value of character literal ' ' is not equal to 32 and if I am not mistaken it is equal to 64.

So depending on selected coding the size of the array will be different.

For ASCII

```
char a[32];
```

For EBCDIC

```
char a[64];
```

Answer (score 4):

`'  '` is a character literal, it has the type `char` - so this is really just a number.

You system is probably using ascii, in which case the ascii value of a space is 32, so this would be the same as

```
char a[32];
```

Answer (score 4):

`' '` is a char literal with value `32` (ASCII code of whitespace). So `char a[' ']` is just `char a[32]`.

Comment: Only if your system is ASCII. Under z/OS for example, you'll find it's `char a[64]` :-)

Answer (score 1):

`char a[' ']` which has the character constant `' '`  character. The integer equivalent of which is 32, the array will be declared of size `32`. `char a[32]`